# CUstom Select Option Box showing only one part of the option

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've a default select option but what I want is to get the specific part of the select option.

In this code for the option I have the numbers plus the text, but What I want is to get only the number once after selecting the option.

```
<select name="" id="">
<option><i>1</i> Public</option>
<option><i>2</i> Private</option>
<option><i>3</i> Only Me</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Assign what you want to the option's value. `<option value="1"><i>1</i> Public</option>` .  [https://jsfiddle.net/q3fkt242/](https://jsfiddle.net/q3fkt242/)

Comment: I want only the number to be displayed after selecting the option

Comment: @Mohamed, if you just want to display NO only as a text then why do you add other string, what you exactly want to achieve with this?

Comment: Look at this this is what I want
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/139417/4167005d094aaeef54ae2b2a25b64dfb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this.

```
"<i>1</i> Public".match(/\d+/)
```

**Example**

```js
$("#test").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val().match(/\d+/));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="test">
<option><i>1</i> Public</option>
<option><i>2</i> Private</option>
<option><i>3</i> Only Me</option>
</select>
```

**Update:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".options").hide();
    $(".header").click(function () {
        console.log("in");
        $(".options").show();
    });
    $(".options li").click(function () {
        console.log($(this));
        console.log($(this).text());
        $(".header").text($(this).text().match(/\d+/));
        $(".options").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"> <i>1</i>
</div>
<div class="options">
    <li><i>1</i> Public</li>
    <li><i>2</i> Private</li>
    <li><i>3</i> Only Me</li>
</div>
```

You can modify div style to make it look like select box.

Comment: I want only the number to be displayed after selecting option

Comment: @Mohamed, if you just want to display NO only as a text then why do you add other string, what you exactly want to achieve with this?

Comment: Somehing like this
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/139417/4167005d094aaeef54ae2b2a25b64dfb

Comment: Happy to help :-) mark it answer so even other can take help from this. :)